# R update in a loop

Tags: r, list

it seems a basic question, but I have the folowwing list and vector:

```
ll <- list(a=c(1,2,1,2,1,1,1),
           b=c("a","v","h","j","w","h", "m"),
           field=c("may","june","may","mars","july", "august", "september")
           id=125887,
           weather="sunny")

bool<-c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
```

My target is to have:

```
ll <- list(a=c(1,2,1),
           b=c("a","v","h"),
           field=c("may","june","may","mars","july", "august", "september")
           id=125887,
           weather="sunny")
```

I can do it by:

```
ll$a <- ll$a[bool]
ll$b <- ll$b[bool]
```

For a lot of modification it is unconvenient. So a little bit more efficient code would be to create the function:

```
f <- function(u){
    ll[[u]] <- ll[[u]][bool]
}
```

Given the vector `vec<-c("a","b")` , I would like to do something like `lapply(vec, f)` but this does not give me directly the result .. R does not work by reference but I wonder if I can update my list directly !

Answer (score 0):

`lapply` passes each item in your list separately to the function you supply. So `f` is receiving `ll$a` as `u`, for example. Instead you'd want:

```
newll = lapply(ll, function(x) x[bool])
```

Or to be a little safer

```
newll = lapply(ll, function(x) if(length(x)==length(bool)) x[bool] else x)
```

Comment: This is misleading since a case can happen where I have an item having the same length as a and b but on which I do not want any extract !

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, you should edit your question to include an example of such a case.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel It's the same problem with all your other methods though and you just haven't realised it. The only reason they kind of work is a coincidence and R's practices on vector recycling.

Comment: @ Senor O : copy/paste my code in a R terminal and you will see my solution works (type ll) since I loop over the vector of names - vec - I want to modify and not over all the elements of the list.

Comment: @Alex Reynolds, the edit is done with an example of such a case.

Answer (score 0):

`lapply()` has a `for()` loop embedded in it so it's not significantly more efficient than a real loop.  Instead of writing a function and breaking the functional programming paradigm by changing data outside of the function, why not just use a for loop at the top level?

```
for (i in 1:2){
  ll[[i]] <- ll[[i]][bool]
}
```

or loop over the whole list and only change where the length is appropriate

```
for (i in seq_along(ll)){
  if (length(ll[[i]])==length(bool)) ll[[i]] <- ll[[i]][bool]
}
```